# Different encoding when using unicode character in Python

Tags: python, python-unicode, unicode-normalization

I'm having problem in Python when met composition unicode instead of built-in unicode. Here is reproduce code:

```
# encoding=utf8

a = ["Địa"]
b = ["Địa"]

print(a)  # ['\xc4\x90i\xcc\xa3a']
print(b)  # ['\xc4\x90\xe1\xbb\x8ba']

print("Địa" in a)  # False
print("Địa" in b)  # True
```

How can I convert/normalize them into the same encoder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `unicodedata.normalize()`:

```
# encoding=utf8
import unicodedata
a = ["Địa"]
b = ["Địa"]

print("Địa" in [unicodedata.normalize('NFC', i) for i in a])
print("Địa" in [unicodedata.normalize('NFC', i) for i in b])
```

This outputs:

```
True
True
```